# How to convert mixed format char vector to datetime in R?

Tags: r, datetime, lubridate

I have a mixed format of character strings representing Date and time. Is there a single lubridate function that convert this vector into proper datetime?

Sample  vector below:

```
> [1] "12/7/2016 0:40"      "12/7/2016 6:23"      "13-07-2016 20:19:50"
> "14-07-2016 07:38:26" "12/7/2016 19:17"      [6] "14-07-2016 08:03:39"
> "12/7/2016 0:07"      "12/7/2016 21:22"     "11/7/2016 16:06"    
> "14-07-2016 17:20:56" [11] "11/7/2016 4:17"      "13-07-2016 09:12:19"
> "11/7/2016 11:31"     "15-07-2016 23:46:20" "12/7/2016 9:59"      [16]
> "14-07-2016 13:50:06" "11/7/2016 7:07"      "11/7/2016 13:41"    
> "15-07-2016 09:10:25" "12/7/2016 15:31"
```

Answer (score 0):

Used `parse_date_time(mixed_format_date, c("dmy_HM", "dmy_HMS")).`

Used `HM` and `HMS` since `hm` and `ms` are currently deprecated.